# Access custom meta_data in processing order email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field, email, order

During a woocommerce order, I store a custom meta data inside the order.

I would like to display that created custom meta data into the "processing order" email.

The following code is included in a plugin .php file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'mm_email_before_order_table', 10, 4 );
function mm_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    $orderid=$order->get_id();
    $voucherid = $order->get_meta( $meta_field );
    $orderdetails = wc_get_order($orderid);
    ...
}
```

It seems that my meta data is not available when sending the email.
Even when I 'echo' the $orderdetails, everything appears except the custom meta data which is missing.

During my email tests which are performed with the *WooCommerce Email Test* addon, everything works fine.

How should I do to access my custom meta data during the processing order email?

**Edit:
I have noticed that the meta information is not available during "processing order" email , but is available during the "order complete " email.
Any clue why?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could use `get_post_meta($order->get_id(), $meta_field, true)`

Comment: Thank you for the support, sadly it does not work
It gives me many information (e.g. billing details) but not the meta field I have in my order.

Comment: How did you add that meta value in the first place? also, you need to replace `$meta_value` with the name of the field you want to retrieve

Comment: To add the custom meta value in the order , I used this :

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'my_api_call');
function my_api_call ($order_id){
 ...
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'code','something' );
        ...
}

What I have noticed is that the meta information is not displayed during "processing order" email , but everything works well during the "order complete " email

Any clue why?

Comment: If you have access to `$order` you should not have a problem getting its meta value, could you update your code to show the new `get_post_meta` that you use?

Comment: I use the same as I wrote in my code ( there is no difference between yours or mine)
Would it be possible that the emails are fired before the meta information is written ? 

That's my guess because if I turn the order to "finish" , the "completed order" email is fired, and in that mail ,everything is fine ...
Would there be a way to add a small delay between the email and the order ?

Comment: So you still use `$order->get_meta` and you haven't tried using `get_post_meta`? Im asking because `$order->get_meta` doesn't work the same as `get_post_meta`

Comment: I have tried, and I received different information, but the meta I was looking for was still unavailable.

Comment: Try checking the order id, it must be incorrect. You used `update_post_meta` so it must be available with `get_post_meta`, nothing special

Comment: My code is correct, when I resend the mail, the meta information is displayed.
I assume the meta information is not available when the email is fired.
Would there be any chance of delay ? Because the information I put in the meta field  comes from an api for example ?